# Pandas Histogram - y axis in time

Tags: matplotlib, pandas, histogram

I have a DataFrame that is indexed with DateTime and on the histogram it shows up with counts.  Each count is 20 secs.
How can I change the y axis to display mins, hours, or days, instead of counts?

Here's the top five rows of my DataFrame:

```
from pandas.lib import Timestamp
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {Timestamp('2013-01-20 00:00:16.726000'): 0.14746094,
                         Timestamp('2013-01-20 00:00:36.726002'): 0.13964844,
                         Timestamp('2013-01-20 00:00:56.726004'): 0.13574219,
                         Timestamp('2013-01-20 00:01:16.725997'): 0.14355469,
                         Timestamp('2013-01-20 00:01:36.725999'): 0.14746094},
                   'B': {Timestamp('2013-01-20 00:00:16.726000'): 3.5716574,
                         Timestamp('2013-01-20 00:00:36.726002'): 3.5716574,
                         Timestamp('2013-01-20 00:00:56.726004'): 3.5716574,
                         Timestamp('2013-01-20 00:01:16.725997'): 3.5716574,
                         Timestamp('2013-01-20 00:01:36.725999'): 3.5716574}})
df.plot()
```

matplotlib v1.2.0
pandas 0.10.1

[image: Histogram]

bump

Comment: could you provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: I added df.head().to_dict() to post above

Comment: currently to create my time axis I'm using the following:    `x = mdates.num2date(x, tz=None)` `x = [dt.replace(tzinfo=None) for dt in x]`

Comment: What version of pandas/matplotlib are you using? It's not clear what you mean when you say "counts" it looks like it plots ok for me (00:00:26, 00:00:36,... as x-ticks).

Comment: Like Andy, I'm confused by what you're trying to do. Isn't the point of a histogram to show counts on the y-axis? You may be trying to force the use of `hist` ... consider taking a step back to construct a bar plot.

Comment: I'm trying to get amount of time on the y label instead of counts.  So it would read hours or days.  So it's easy to read and say oh we are spending this much time at this value.  I think I need to work on scaling the label and writing to that, but I've put this on the back burner.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, df.plot will not show an histogram (i.e. a distribution of values) but evolution curves of values indexed by timestamps.

The following snippet displays an histogram of values using not 'counts' but intervals duration as y-axis weights (all equal to 20s seconds as you specified, but they could differ for each values).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.hist(weights=np.repeat(20,5))
plt.ylabel('Cumulated intervals duration [sec]')
```

[image: histogram]